# Function generators Python

Tags: python, generator

I was trying to implement a function generator to be used n times.
My idea was to create a generator object, then assign that object to another variable and call the re-assigned variable as the function, example:

```
def generator:
   [...]
   yield ...

for x in xrange(10):
   function = generator
   print function(50)
```

When I call the print function, I observe that `function(50)` was not called. Instead the output is: `<generator object...>`. I was trying to use this function 10 times by assigning it to a generator function, and using this new variable as the generator function.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Please post a runnable code example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generator Functions return generator objects. You need to do `list(gen)` to convert them into a `list` or just iterate over them.

```
>>> def testFunc(num):
        for i in range(10, num):
            yield i


>>> testFunc(15)
<generator object testFunc at 0x02A18170>
>>> list(testFunc(15))
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> for elem in testFunc(15):
        print elem


10
11
12
13
14
```

This question explains more about it: [The Python yield keyword explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create generator objects with a generator expression:

```
>>> (i for i in range(10, 15))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0258AF80>
>>> list(i for i in range(10, 15))
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> n, m = 10, 15
>>> print ('{}\n'*(m-n)).format(*(i for i in range(n, m)))
10
11
12
13
14
```